# What makes Spring a great framework (features)?

Tags: spring

I'm new to web development and Java EE and I understand that Spring is a Java framework for those purposes but when I watch all those fancy videos I still don't get the advantages. More specifically:

1. Is it similar to Java EE APIs but improved?
2. Does it include standard classes for modifing different types of projects?
3. Do you feel it saves you time when writing code functionality?
4. Does Spring tie me to certain products like servers, database, technologies?
5. What kind of web hosting characteristics do you need?
6. Are JSP and servlets obsolete?
7. How would you describe a regular work day of Spring application development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent most of my time as a developer developing applications in Spring. It can be a bit difficult to figure out at first, especially if you're new to programming, but once you understand it I think it's a really powerful, helpful framework with a lot of options.

Let me try answering your questions point by point:

1. *similar apis to Java EE but improved?* Yes, it is similar. It also lets you use a lot of the generic Java specifications instead of spring-specific ones if you want. (Like using @Inject instead of @Autowired). It has a lot of ways in which it makes things easier for you, though, like nice exception handling options, good hibernate or jdbc "template" classes, etc.
2. *it includes standard classes to modify for different types of projects?* Yes and no. I use a lot of its classes, but I don't usually have to subclass or modify them. More often you'll want to pull in different Spring dependencies for different projects. You might want spring-data-mongodb if you're using mongodb. You might want spring-security-oauth2 if you want to use that. All those different dependency options come with a whole slew of classes and options to make integrating with different technologies easier.
3. *do you feel it saves you time when writing code functionality?* This really depends on the project. For a really simple project, a more convention-based higher-abstraction framework like Grails might be faster. Spring Data and the Spring Rest annotations, and stuff like that do help me develop faster for "real" projects though.
4. *does spring ties me to certain products like servers, database, technologies?* No.
5. *which kind of web hosting characteristics do you need?* You can chose. Maybe you can clarify what exactly you mean here a bit better though?
6. *are JSP and servlets discarded?* No, Spring MVC uses JSPs extensively. On the other hand, you can do it all RESTfully and not use any JSPs at all.

Comment: thank you a lot, i do appreciate this. You cleared all my doubts But now i'll practice and learn the basics(jsp,servlets) to be able for using advance features.

Answer (score 0):

To understand edge of `Spring framework` over others, you first have to learn Java EE (specifically `JSP and Servlets`). Earlier `EJB` was used to create `Enterprise Java EE applications`, but today 2/3rd of `Enterprise applications` are created in `Spring`. If you know both of them (EJB and Spring), then you can compare and understand the *edge* easily.

Comment: Java EE these days is a little more than just EJB ;) Specifically relevant here is CDI, but other Java EE technologies like JAX-RS, JSF, JPA, Batching etc are all relevant as they have Spring counterparts as well.

Comment: thank you, you are right, now i'm learning JSP and Java EE in order to compare the advantages